# PHPMoAdmin web interface can't connect to MongoDB

Tags: php, mongodb

I've installed the [PHPMoAdmin Web UI](http://www.phpmoadmin.com/) on Windows 10 using XAMPP.

But when I navigate to the place I've installed it in my browser:

[image]

I get a message saying that the PHPMongoDB extension is missing.

Yet, when I look at my phpinfo page, the mongodb extension is right there:

[image]

This is the code that tries to connect to MongoDB:

```
protected function _mongo() {
    $connection = (!MONGO_CONNECTION ? 'mongodb://localhost:27017' : MONGO_CONNECTION);
    $Mongo = (class_exists('MongoClient') === true ? 'MongoClient' : 'Mongo');
    return (!REPLICA_SET ? new $Mongo($connection) : new $Mongo($connection, array('replicaSet' => true)));
}
```

And I am able to connect to mongodb on the command line:

```
PS C:\Users\bluet> mongosh
Current Mongosh Log ID: 6171fd3f9a9ff1c66d90e4f7
Connecting to:          mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?directConnection=true&serverSelectionTimeoutMS=2000
Using MongoDB:          5.0.1
Using Mongosh:          1.0.3

For mongosh info see: https://docs.mongodb.com/mongodb-shell/

------
   The server generated these startup warnings when booting:
   2021-10-21T17:37:26.117-04:00: Access control is not enabled for the database. Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted
------

Warning: Found ~/.mongorc.js, but not ~/.mongoshrc.js. ~/.mongorc.js will not be loaded.
  You may want to copy or rename ~/.mongorc.js to ~/.mongoshrc.js.
```

What can I do to get PHPMoAdmin to connect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [phpMoAdmin project](https://github.com/MongoDB-Rox/phpMoAdmin-MongoDB-Admin-Tool-for-PHP) is not maintained anymore (the last commit was in 2017) and, as stated
[here](https://github.com/MongoDB-Rox/phpMoAdmin-MongoDB-Admin-Tool-for-PHP/issues/29),
the PHP7 mongodb extension is not supported:

> This is on the to-do list. Supporting the new MongoDB extension is a big job as the entire syntax has changed, and the only supported-method to continue to use the (substantially more user-friendly) legacy-syntax is to include a userland PHP library, which is not an ideal option for phpMoAdmin since one of the key ease-of-use factors is that it is contained in a single-file.

A [comment](https://github.com/MongoDB-Rox/phpMoAdmin-MongoDB-Admin-Tool-for-PHP/issues/29#issuecomment-605653352) mentions a fork for PHP7:

> I forked the project [here](https://github.com/ali-khalili/phpMoAdmin-php7) to make it work with PHP7 and mongodb/mongodb package (so, one requires to install package with composer). The overall functionalities seem to work now.

[Another comment](https://github.com/MongoDB-Rox/phpMoAdmin-MongoDB-Admin-Tool-for-PHP/issues/29#issuecomment-657232713) gives a list of alternative projects:

> Here are some alternatives to phpMoAdmin:
>
> https://github.com/lovetheidea/MoaDB
> https://github.com/tetreum/mongolo
> https://github.com/SamuelTS/MongoDB-PHP-GUI

Comment: Great info! Thank you.